# Running multiple LoopBack instances in one app?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm planning a REST API for multiple projects and wondering if they can be build in one app.

Would it be possible to

1. separate the URLs to /api/app1/ and /api/app2/
2. have independent models with the same name, so that /api/app1/model1 != /api/app2/model1 - maybe by using different databases?
3. have a shared ACL between these two instances? E. a. creating and updating one user who has different access rules for every instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yes, it would
2. yes, it would
3. yes, it would

Comment: 1. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678387/how-to-run-multiple-strongloop-loopback-apps-on-the-same-server)?
2. With different databases?
3. Well... are there any tutorials for beginners?

Comment: 1. yes 2. yes 3. there is a npm package for acl https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl but if you want to do your own for studying or something else, it is easy to find acl nodejs tutorials on the internet